# Would this be a binomial probability problem?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Asthma is an important health problem for inner-city children, frequently resulting
in hospital admissions if symptoms become exacerbated. A study is proposed in
which children will be randomized to either an active intervention or control intervention. It is expected that 30% of the children in the active group versus 10% of the children in the control group will have an improvement in asthma symptoms.

Suppose that 50 households are randomized per group. In the active intervention group, 14 of the 50 children had an improvement in symptoms compared
with 6 out of 50 control intervention children. Test the hypothesis that active
intervention has a higher rate of improvement than control intervention group.

Can someone help me with this problem? I have no ideal how to approach it.

Comment: Do you have formulae for testing hypotheses on two proportions?

Comment: @Yes, i do. But how do i set up the hypothesis? Ho: p1=p2 and Ha:p1>p2? Would that be right?

Comment: Exactly. Remember that the alternative hypothesis is the question you wish to test.

Comment: For the 'active' group you have $\hat p_a = 14/50$ and for the 'control' group you have $\hat p_c =6/50.$ You wish to test $H_0: p_a = p_c$ or $H_0: p_a - p_c = 0$ against $H_a: p_a > p_c$ or $H_a: p_a - p_c > 0.$ The natural test statistic involves $D=\hat p_a - \hat p_c.$ For sample sizes of 50 you can use a normal approximation assuming $H_0$ to be true. Standardize to get $Z = \frac{D - E(D)}{SD(D)/\sqrt{n}},$ where $Z$ is aprx std normal. You can find details in most mid-level applied stat texts, and there are implementations in R, Minitab, and many other stat software packages.